# Updating a Jar file with updates in input Excel

Tags: java, multithreading, jar, apache-poi, data-synchronization

I need to create a Jar file which will read an excel and display as output, the existing data and the updated data.
This file needs to keep on running and displaying the Excel data as output. Any update that has been done on the Excel recently needs to be reflected in the output, along with the previous data.
I know how to create a Jar file, i am also able to read an excel file using Apache POI.
I just need an idea regarding how during every run, if the Excel is updated, that updated values can be displayed.
Do we need to implement threading,synchronization? If so, then how?

Comment: This is not clear. How is the Excel file  being updated? Not by POI is assume, because in that case you would know it was being updated.

Comment: @Over_Curious What is in your eyes a jar file? (Question for preventing missunderstandings)

Comment: reporter- Jar file is a java archive file. It is a collection of classes, metadata and resources which are packed into one module. It is like a library file which can be added and used in a program

Comment: fvu- I am not sure how the Excel file is getting updated. I fact that is what my query here is in my post. I am using POI to read an Excel using java code in Eclipse. Now i want a thread which will keep on running and after a time interval(say 1 minute) it will check whether the Excel file has been updated recently or not. If it has been updated then the new file content will be displayed

Answer (score 2):

Synchronization does only work inside of your Java process. Assuming that an external process creates/updates the Excel file therefore synchronization will not help you.

The best chance you have is to listen for file-system changes of the Excel file (see  WatchService class) and access the file after it has been changed.
For avoiding (or better minimize) file access conflicts I would open the file, copy the data to memory and then directly close the file. 
Alternatively you could copy the file and then operate on the copied file. In both cases conflicts can still occur if the program writing the Excel file tries to perform changes while you are accessing the file.
Potential errors are errors because of blocked file or inconsistent data.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I will look into the solution that you provided